# Spring Boot - Profiles (application.properties) to define baseUrl for HTTP requests

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, profile

The situation is that I have two api projects, API A does HTTP requests to API B. Both API's are deployed to a development and production environment.

What I want to achieve is the following: Build the project based on a specific profile (dev or prod) so that the code can use a particular baseurl to talk with the correct api on the correct environment.

So if I build API A based on prod flag, I want it to use the specific url to make http requests to API B that is deployed on it's own prod environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're referring to profiles of maven, however you should probably check out spring profiles. The concept should change :

You're not supposed to **build** different artifacts for different environments.

Instead create a spring profile in service A:

```
application-dev.properties:

url.addr=dev-service-host:1234
```

```
application-prod.properties:

url.addr=prod-service-b-host:4321
```

Then run the application with `--spring.profiles.active=dev` (or `prod`) flag.

Spring boot will load the correct definitions automatically because the dev/prod matches the suffix of properties file

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Almost got it to work. Do you perhaps know how to run the application? Could you please provide me with the full command to run it with the flag?

Comment: If you've run mvn package and got the artifact, then, assuming you're in the folder with the artifact, you can type `java -jar myapp.jar` --spring.profiles.active=prod`. Of course you have to make sure that the spring-boot application is built correctly (with spring-boot-maven plugin). Instead of myapp.jar use the artifact full name.

Comment: Again, thanks for your reponse. I have the next problem when I use the command. "Unable to access jarfile dairy-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar". Is it because it cannot find it? I really need help..

Comment: after `mvn package` succeeds You should go to "target" directory and there you'll see the artifact...

Comment: I posted another post, maybe that is a is a little bit more clear: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60205741/azure-startup-command-unable-to-access-jarfile-app-jar

Answer (score 0):

You can define Spring-Boot profile as:

`spring.profiles.active=prod`

You also should have profiled `.properties` files in `resources`:

- in `application-dev.properties` you should have `api.b.url={api_b_url_on_dev_environment}`
- in `application-prod.properties` you should have `api.b.url={api_b_url_on_prod_environment}`

**Or** if you don't want to recompile your application after changing properties you may use outside `.properties` files.

In order for them to be included during app's deployment do the following:

- in some `config` directory add `application-dev.properties` and `application-prod.properties`
- deploy you app with the following properties: `--spring.profiles.active=dev` and `--spring.config.additional-location=config/application.properties`

This way the outside profiled properties will be included in deployment process. These `.properties` files have the highest priority in Spring.

Comment: Thanks your your reply. How could I run the project based on the configuration file?

Comment: You can use it as such: `java -jar your_application.jar --spring.profiles.active=prod --spring.config.additional-location=config/application.properties`  This will use your `/resources/application-prod.properties` and your external `/config/application-prod.properties` (if you have any)